# How custom DevTools Elements sidebar pane can communicate to panel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating my custom Elements sidebar pane like this:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
    "MyPane",
    function (sidebar) {
        sidebar.setPage('my-pane.html');
    }
);
```

my-pane.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="my-pane.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- custom UI -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside my-pane.js i'm watching currently selected element:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function() {
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("$0", function (res) {
       <!-- process res and want to push detailed results into custom panel -->
    });
});
// expecting request from panel here
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, _, sendResponse) {
    console.log(msg, _, sendResponse);
});
```

Up to the point above everything works just fine: I can get a selection and build a custom HTML UI around it in a pane. Going further, I want to display some more detailed UI in another Panel. This is what i'm trying (immediately after pane creation):

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    'My details',
    'icon.png',
    'my-panel.html',
    function (panel) {
        panel.onShown.addListener(function (window) {
            chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

And these lines fail with (in)famous:

> Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not
>   exist.

Is sendMessage/onMessage pattern a correct way to communicate between pane and panel, both represented as .html pages?

**EDIT**

Tried to avoid DevTools logistics altogether and access pages via DOM (both *my-pane.html* and *my-panel.html* appear to be in `<iframe/>`s within a single parent page):

```
..
panel.onShown.addListener(function (window) {
    console.log(["PANEL",
       window
           .top
           .frames[0] // Assume this is my-pane.html
           .document
           .getElementsByTagName('ol')
    ]);
});
..
```

This didn't work:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   chrome-extension://<..>/devtools.html from
>   frame with URL
>   chrome-extension://<..>/devtools.html.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

**EDIT 2**

Silly me! Of course the above assumption about the first `<iframe/>` being the right one is completely false. The following produces more meaningful result:

```
panel.onShown.addListener(function (window) {
    for (var i = 0; i < window.top.frames.length; i++) {
        try {
            console.log(["PANEL",
                window.top.frames[i].document.getElementsByTagName('ol')
            ]);
            break;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('BAD!', e);
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT 3 (Solution but not the *answer*)**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    'My Panel',
    'icon.png',
    'my-panel.html', // Must define function callbackInMyPanelPage(doc) { .. }
    function (panel) {
        panel.onShown.addListener(function (window) {
            for (var i = 0; i < window.top.frames.length; i++) {
                try {
                    // Use any unique marker to identify our pane document,
                    // at worst case a security exception will be thrown..
                    var $el = window.top.frames[i].document.getElementById('myPane');

                    if ($el) {
                        try {
                            // pass pane's document to panel page
                            window.callbackInMyPanelPage(window.top.frames[i].document);
                        } catch(ex) {} // Don't interfere with a handler below 
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.warn('Cannot access <iframe/>', e);
                }
            }
        });
     }
 );
```

**Bonus: a visualisation of what sort of communication (green arrow) i was trying to achieve**

[image]

Comment: Your code is missing a definition of an `onMessage` event listener.

Comment: @RobW thanks for reminder: i've tried generic **chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(..)** in two places:

1. Inside _my-pane.js_, right after subscribing to onSelectionChanged
2. Inside _devtools.js_, in between of pane and panel creation.

As far as i understand this is called [Simple one-time requests](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: Are you sure that no error occurred which caused the event binding to fail? You can open another devtools instance inside a devtools instance to look for errors (I didn't have the time to thoroughly follow the flow of your code; you could use several `console.log`s, or the quick n dirty `alert('somenumber')` to check this yourself).

Comment: So far got onMessage event handler working after putting it into  background.js. But that's what i'd like to avoid exactly. Instead, i'd prefer that my-pane.html and my-panel.html talking directly to each other. This is certainly [possible](http://code.google.com/p/google-axs-chrome/source/browse/trunk/chromevox/chromeshades/devtools/loader.js) when NOT using HTML pages as pane and panel content.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this but avoiding `Edit 3 solution`??
I started doing `Edit 3 solution` as a way to do it, and now that I'm looking to do it properly with `sendMessage` I am hitting a wall. I seem to be sending the messages, but they are not being picked up in `panel.html` > `panel.js`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment

> So far got onMessage event handler working after putting it into
>   background.js. But that's what i'd like to avoid exactly. Instead, i'd
>   prefer that my-pane.html and my-panel.html talking directly to each
>   other. This is certainly possible when NOT using HTML pages as pane
>   and panel content.

I figured out what happend...

Your panel/pane isn't a extension process, it's considered a content-script.
So you'll need to use [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage) instead of [chrome.extension.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage).